# Ajax success being called even with validation

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

On my Create page I have jquery validation along with jquery.ajax.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

$(document).ready(function () {
    var settings = {};
    settings.baseUri = '@Request.ApplicationPath';
    var infoGetUrl = "";
    if (settings.baseUri === "/ProjectName") {
        infoGetUrl = settings.baseUri + "/controllername/create";
    } else {
        infoGetUrl = settings.baseUri + "controllername/create/";
    }

    $("#Create-Btn").on("click",
        function (e) {
            $("form").validate({
                submitHandler: function () {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    $.ajax({
                        method: "POST",
                        url: infoGetUrl,
                        data: $("form").serialize(),
                        success: function (data) {
                            toastr.success("Successfully Created.");
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            var status = capitalizeFirstLetter(textStatus);
                            var error = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
                            toastr.error(status + " - " + error.message);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });

    function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
        return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
    }
});
```

Now when I initially go to the page, and hit submit (to test out the jquery validation).. I get the success message.. not the error message.  The form is not submitting because I am leaving required fields blank.

Any reason on why that is happening?

**UPDATE**

In controller I now have this:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    //do something
else
{
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Validation Failed");
}
```

But now, when I try and show the `Validation Failed` message in my

```
var error = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
toastr.error(status + " - " + error.message);
```

I get an invalid character error from the `$.parseJSON`.. and that is because I am getting returned an entire page of html..

**UPDATE**

Nevermind, I just deleted the `$.parseJSON` line.. and replaced error.message with errorThrown from the error function and that worked.

Comment: Not sure if typo/would have any reason on what's happening but you are missing '#' before `form`, `$("#form").validate({` and `data: $("#form").serialize(),`...

Comment: @Sandman You are assuming that my form has an id called `#form`.. I am simply serializing the entire form object.. and since there is only one form on my page.. I don't need to give it an id since it is already unique

Comment: I am _assuming_ as it is not clearly indicated otherwise... ;) Any chance of posting up some server code (as hinted at by @Chris)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is entirely dependent on your server-side code, which you haven't posted, so it's pretty impossible to say with any certainty what the exact issue is. However, you should bear in mind that for AJAX, success means a 200-family response was returned, while error means the response contained some other family of status codes (400-500 families). Off the top of my head, I'm not actually sure what would occur with a 300-family status code, but I think that would actually hit your success method, too. Don't quote me on that, though.

Regardless, the point is that if you're simply returning a JSON object indicating an error occurred, but still sending the response with 200, that's a success, not an error. There's actually two ways you could view the situation. You could look at the AJAX success/failure as merely an indication of whether the request itself had issues. In that scenario, you would handle validation errors in your "success" callback and use the "error" callback to handle edge-cases, where there server threw a 500, for example. Alternatively, you can look at anything but a 100% successful transaction as an error. Then, your "success" callback would only handle a complete success and your "error" callback would handle all cases where there was some problem, including validation errors. To effect that situation, your server action would need to return something like a 400 Bad Request on validation errors.

Comment: Okay, on server in my action, I have done a conditional statement.. if modelstate.isvalid then do x.. else return HttpStatusCode.BadRequest.. updating question